# beamer blocks in ordinary article-style document

Tags: beamer

Is there a way to emulate  beamer blocks, e.g., alert/example, in 
ordinary pdflatex in article documents? Is there a pure tikz way of
doing this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Colored text? The box around theorem environments?

Comment: Rounded corners, shadows, two colors (title/body).
I have seen some tikz examples, but they are not 100% satisfactory.

Answer (score 22):

With version 2.00 of [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and its `skin` library it's possible to include `beamer` blocks in `non-beamer` documents. And now this blocks can break between columns and pages.

Here you have an example:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings,shadows}

\title{Beamer blocks in \texttt{article.cls} with \texttt{tcolorbox (v 2.00)}}
\author{xxxxxx}

\newenvironment{myexampleblock}[1]{%
    \tcolorbox[beamer,%
    noparskip,breakable,
    colback=LightGreen,colframe=DarkGreen,%
    colbacklower=LimeGreen!75!LightGreen,%
    title=#1]}%
    {\endtcolorbox}

\newenvironment{myalertblock}[1]{%
    \tcolorbox[beamer,%
    noparskip,breakable,
    colback=LightCoral,colframe=DarkRed,%
    colbacklower=Tomato!75!LightCoral,%
    title=#1]}%
    {\endtcolorbox}

\newenvironment{myblock}[1]{%
    \tcolorbox[beamer,%
    noparskip,breakable,
    colback=LightBlue,colframe=DarkBlue,%
    colbacklower=DarkBlue!75!LightBlue,%
    title=#1]}%
    {\endtcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{myblock}{Example of \texttt{myblock}}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{myblock}

\begin{myexampleblock}{Example of \texttt{myexampleblock}}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myexampleblock}

\begin{myalertblock}{Example of \texttt{myalertblock}}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myalertblock}

\end{document}
```

with its result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! One minor but helpful modification which allows mathematics to appear in the title is to slightly modify the newenvironment command, replacing "title=#1" with "title={#1}".

Answer (score 4):

It is relatively easy to reproduce similar boxes using TikZ in a non-beamer document.  For example, [see here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/).  Do you really need it to look exactly the same as in beamer?  If so, you can just look at how it is implemented within beamer; I think it is defined either in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` or `beamerinnerthemeinmargin.sty`.