# use beamercolorbox in book

Tags: beamer, packages, document-classes

How can i use beamer commands and environments like beamercolorbox in other document classes like article or book?

Is there an alternative to beamercolorbox in another package or document class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [beamer blocks in ordinary article-style document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/beamer-blocks-in-ordinary-article-style-document)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is new package just released at CTAN which might be what you want.  You need to properly install tcolorbox.  The following MWE

```
%% This MWE is an extract from 
%% tcolorbox-example.tex: an example for tcolorbox
%% Contained in the tcolorbox zip file

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5,colframe=blue!75!black,title=My title]
  My box with my title.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!5,colframe=yellow!75!black,title=My title]
  I can do this also with a title.
  \tcblower
  Lower part of my box.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!10,colframe=red!75!black,title=Here I am]
  \input{\jobname_ex.tex}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Produces

[image: Sample tcolorbox]

```
\end{document}
```