# Expressing beamer styles in ordinary LaTeX

Tags: beamer

I use beamer for all my slides, and Ipe for most of my drawings. This has become a little inconvenient since my slides involve lots of pictures, and so my typical beamer frame really only looks like

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{something}
\multiinclude{lots of ipe animation}
\end{frame}
```

This is a little annoying since all I'm really using from beamer is the external styling and titling (the outer style for the most part). Since Ipe has the ability to include arbitrary latex in a preamble, my question is the following:

> Is there a relatively easy way to take the theme elements I want from
>   beamer and package them into a stand alone latex file that I can
>   include ?

As a concrete example, my current beamer style looks like this:

```
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Pittsburgh}
  \useoutertheme{shadow}
  \useinnertheme{rounded}
}
\usecolortheme{rose}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme[rgb={0.5,0,0}]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

Comment: Related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/beamer-blocks-in-ordinary-article-style-document

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no, at least not without a lot of effort. There is a lot of stuff happening 'behind the scenes' in `beamer` to make the theme system work, draw different slide elements, *etc.* You could of course pick those to pieces by hand and minimise the code for the layout/appearance you want, but it would be a *big* job and I suspect easier to simply start from a standard `article` layout and add stuff!